# Put folder name into a cell based on criteria of another cell

Tags: excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using FSO to insert folder name into cell based on criteria being met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270561/using-fso-to-insert-folder-name-into-cell-based-on-criteria-being-met)

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- Check to see where the last cell with data is located in column "A" (works)
- Paste the data into column "A" to wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets") (works)
- Find the name of the folder, which is fsoFol.Name (works)
- For each pasted cell in "A", check for a value.
- If there's a value, I need to put the fsoFol.Name in the offset(0,5)--this should be able to reference off of the firstRange variable, but per cell, and I can't figure out how to do it --or the best way to do that.  (doesn't work)
- if there's no value, skip it.

Suggestions?  Thank you in advance.

```
 Dim FSO As Object, fld As Object, Fil As Object
    Dim fsoFile As Object
    Dim fsoFol As Object

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = FSO.getfolder(folderPath)

    If FSO.folderExists(fld) Then
        For Each fsoFol In FSO.getfolder(folderPath).subfolders
            For Each fsoFile In fsoFol.Files
                If Mid(fsoFile.Name, InStrRev(fsoFile.Name, ".") + 1) = "xls" Then
    fileName = fsoFile.Name
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wbkCS = Workbooks.Open(fsoFile.Path)

    If fileName Like "V*.xls" Then
    wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("S4:S2000").Copy
       With wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets")
    Set firstRange = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 
        firstRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    For Each firstRange.Value in wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets")
        If firstRange.Value <> "" Then
        firstRange.Offset(0, 5).Value = fsoFol.Name
                  End If
            Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax of the `For Each a In b`  loop is wrong: `b` returns a collection (in this case the `Cells` in a `Worksheet`, `a` must be of the type of members of that collection (in this case `Range.

So correct syntax is

```
For Each firstRange in wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets")
```

That said, you really don't want to do this.  What the loop will do is check *every* cell on the sheet (billions!), that will be *so* slow.  Also, it will run away, since each time it finds a non blank cell it creates another one to tigger the `If`.

**Update**

Based on your comment, I think what you want is:

- For every cell you just pasted in column `A` that is not blank, put the value of `fsoFol.Name` in column`F`

If so, try this (replace from `wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("S4:S2000").Copy` down)

```
Dim rngSource As Range
Set rngSource = wbkCS.Worksheets("Cut Sheet").Range("S4:S2000")
With wbkVer.Worksheets("Cutsheets")
    Set firstRange = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngSource.Rows.Count, 1)
    firstRange.Value = rngSource.Value
    firstRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(0, 5) = fsoFol.Name
End With
```

Comment: What you _do_ want to do is not clear.  Perhaps add some screen shots of the required output.

Comment: The "simple" way to put it... is that when data is pasted into column A, I need it to also paste the folder name into the offset column(0,5).  Maybe that's a better way to look at it.  However, since I'm copy/pasting a range of data (S4:S2000) I don't know how I would do that.

Comment: The other consideration is that there will be varying ranges of data from other sources copy/pasted below that range in column A (hence the bottom/up cell search).

Comment: Once again, Chris you are the man!  Exactly what I was looking for.  By the way, these code adjustments have been helping me learn immensely from my mistakes and learning alternative ways to do things, so I thank you!